# Retrieve gps location from timezone

Tags: jquery, timezone, momentjs

Is there any method to get GPS location from given timezone in jQuery or in moment.js? I searched a lot but not getting any result...can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: GPS from timezone? You know how big timezones can be right? What GPS from that timezone do you need? The center? Any? All?

Comment: I want any gps from that timezone or center gps

Comment: Not my downvote, but probably because the ask is rather odd and the question doesn't show much detail.  You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then revise your question.  Specifically, you might include examples of input and desired output and explain the context around the usage so the reader understands *why* you need this.  Also, jQuery is unrelated - so that is a distraction rather than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find latitude and longitudes for *some* of the IANA/TZDB time zones in the [zone.tab](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab) file.

For moment.js, this data gets copied into the "meta" files of the moment-timezone project.  You can find the latest JSON data [in the file here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/meta/latest.json).  For example, scroll down to about line 1900 or so and you'll see the `zone` array containing lat/long fields and other information for the zones where they are known.

Note that this data is *not* part of the moment-timezone data file distribution, and is not yet included in any public API in the moment-timezone project, so you'd have to write the code yourself to search the JSON and find the result.  There are also no guarantees about forward compatibility, maintenance, etc.

Also, recognize that many time zones are not applicable for a single location.  For example `"Etc/UTC"` is a valid time zone identifier, but UTC is not observed by a single location.  There are several locations that are *aligned* to UTC+00:00, but someone from Senegal would probably find it odd if you located them in Iceland just because both share the same time zone offset.  In other words, in the *common case* this is doable, but in the *general case* it is not.